# UIViews are overlapping in scrollview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

in my app I added two views as `subviews` of `UIScrollview` but I saw that `view2` overlapped `view1` and always be able to see only one view.

```
view1's frame : (0,0,1024,768)
view2's frame : (1024,0,1024,768)
scrollView's frame       : (0,0,1024,768)
scrollView's contentSize : (2048,768)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: you are adding view in storyboard or by code?

Comment: Scrollview is in xib and views adding through code.

Comment: Its better to use page view controller than scroll view

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the two subviews to your scrollView ?